# Disqus SSO settings

Tags: single-sign-on, disqus

I get some confused after visit the https://disqus.com/api/sso/ (the page make settings of SSO like below)

[image: SSO settings of Disqus]

My development environment there are test and production, but I see the tip says "Once you configure your remote domain you cannot change it!".

It means this account only can support one domain (should use for production, else I need to create another account), right?

If Yes, can give me an example for how to fill in there fields about "Name" and "Slug".

Name's placeholder is "My Domain", but the tip looks like need I fill in the shortname (or other strings).

Slug's placeholder is "domain", but the tip's ex looks like fill in the "4602fc349ffc0ad649190e937f2a5f14" (in short not a domain), and what is it doing?

Last, I not find the settings of SSO Domain like below

[image: SSO Domain]

Is it show up after I finish the SSO settings?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I get response from Disqus Support, they said..

As the Domain is only to identify the SSO application internally, you may want to set this as the same as your site shortname, so it will be clearly associated with that forum.

The slug will be the prefix to the SSO accounts your site will create for your users, so this must be unique, and can be whatever unique name you’d like to choose to identify a user of your site: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5w6etov45huj3gy/Screenshot%202015-09-11%2014.06.56.png?dl=0

So the 'Name' I input my website's shortname, also the 'Slug', and the settings of SSO Domain is correctly show up after I finished it.